# Is it possible for partial derivatives to not commute because of non-trivial spatial "topology"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, physics

In this [1985 paper by Callan and Harvey](http://theory.uchicago.edu/%7Eharvey/pdf_files/callan_harvey_1984.pdf#page=4), Eq. $11$ seems to claim that in the presence of an infinitely extended string-like topological defect, partial derivatives do not seem to commute on the string:

$$
[\partial_x, \partial_y]\, \theta = 2\pi \delta(x)\delta(y)\,. \tag{11}
$$

This is apparently "because of the topology of the axion string." I do not quite follow. Can someone please explain the reasoning to me in a bit more detail? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about the topology of strings, but Schwarz's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) states the conditions needed for partial differential operators to commute; one of them is that a neighbourhood of a point should be contained in the domain.